# error when I include iomanip

Tags: c++

I was just starting writing a program, when I noticed something I do not understand.
I have defined a structure called "time".
When I try to define a structure variable called "time1", it send out an error: "expected an ';'".
But when I remove the header file "iomanip" the error disappears! And when I include it again the error comes back. Why does this happen?

Comment: Possible clash with http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/time/ ?

Comment: @BoBTFish, thought so too at first, but does time.h have anything to do with iomaip?

Comment: Wouldn't have thought so, but who knows what might get included? I made a quick attempt to recreate the error and didn't see it with g++ 4.1.2 (hard without the code obviously) so maybe he's using an implementation that includes some extensions for formatting time or something? Complete stab in the dark.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee404887.aspx maybe?

Answer (score 4):

Let's try out this piece of code:

```
#include <iomanip>

struct time
{
    int a;
};

int main()
{
    time t1;
}
```

Here's the error, and a warning that I'm getting in QtCreator when I try to compile this (mycompiler is g++ 4.6.3). The compiler thinks that `time` here is not a statement, but a function name:

[image]

Apparently, `<iomanip>` somehow includes `<time.h>`, and `time.h` has a [function called time()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/time/). So, basicaly, just rename your structure to "myTime" or something like that.

Comment: Ah yes, I'm seeing the same error now I changed my test a bit. Although includes as `<ctime>` are *supposed* to be wrapped in the `std` namespace, in which case this error shouldn't happen. But still, best to try to be unique with names.

Comment: The names were *supposed* to be wrapped in namespace `std`, but in practice mostly they were not. The C++11 standard now says that the names being visible in the global namespace is ok.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to rename the name of struct, then you can change it to this:

```
#include <iomanip>

struct time
{
    int a;
};

int main()
{
    struct time t1;
}
```